# php prepared statement

Tags: php

It does not print the result. Dont know why. Everything is neatly commented

I get no error displays, no syntax blasphemes, it just does not print any result. However, I do know that the values are passed by the form to this processing php page, so the error is not in there. In the DB I have encrypted all fields except 'company'- Thus, I want to see if this will work by trying to fetch the results back.

```
// 1. Creating a new server connection

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'developers');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
// 2, Creating statement object
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

// 3, Creating a prepared statement
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT company FROM accesoweb WHERE username = AES_DECRYPT(?, 'salt')")) {

//4. Binding the variable to replace the ?
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

    printf("Error: %d.\n", $stmt->errno);


// 5. Executing query
    $stmt->execute();


// 6. Binding the result columns to variables
    $stmt->bind_result($company); 


// 7. Fetching the result of the query
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $company; 
    }

// 8. Closing the statement object
   $stmt->close();

// 9. Closing the connection

 $mysqli->close();
```

## }

The inserting code that I just included in the MySQL was:

```
INSERT INTO accesoweb (company, username,email,password)
VALUES
 ('hola',
AES_ENCRYPT('maria','salt'),
AES_ENCRYPT('sumail','salt'),
AES_ENCRYPT('password',' salt')


);
```

So, that row above(actually, the "company" is what I am trying to recover through the PHP code

Comment: Is PHP or the webserver configured to output errors? Try a simpler script with debug trace and progressively add the code to see which line it fails on.

Comment: well, it does complain when i write wrong, it has been complaining all day, it is just that it stopped because 'presumably' i wiped all errors. In fact, I have this: error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); at the top of my script

Comment: If I remember correctly, `prepare` is a method of the MySQLi object, not the MySQLiStatement object.

Comment: @Truth Both objects have a `prepare()` method, `MySQLi::prepare()` is just a shortcut so you don't have to call `stmt_init()`. I suspect you're thinking in PDO.

Comment: @iaintunderstand Your problem is most likely that the query returned no results - check the value of `$stmt->num_rows` to confirm.

Comment: It read number of rows = 0 upon printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);. So, how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT company FROM accesoweb WHERE username = AES_DECRYPT(?, 'salt')
```

Should be

```
SELECT company FROM accesoweb WHERE username = AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'salt')
```

OR

```
SELECT company FROM accesoweb WHERE AES_DECRYPT(username, 'salt') = ?
```

Comment: Bingo man!  It is now 20:51. Been with it, since 09:00 writing the full code, going nuts through the internet for lack of a reliable example. That is why a book is so necessary. I could not find a reliable comprehensive tutorial so I had no way to learn, but by trial and error and bits here and there. Than you!!

Comment: that's a terrible logic bug to spot!